# mysql database functions. I STUCK

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get user's friends then get their points. I coded 3 function for that. but i stuck at geting friends points.

Here is my code:

```
function GET_POINT($p_uid){
    if($p_uid){
        $user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE fid='{$p_uid}'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_info)) {
                $point = $row['point'];
                return $point;
        }
    }
}
function GET_FRIENDS($fl_uid){
    if($fl_uid){
        $friend_list_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE fid='{$fl_uid}'");
        $friend_list = mysql_fetch_array($friend_list_query);
        return $friend_list;
    }
}
function GET_FRIEND_POINTS($fp_uid){
    $friend_array = GET_FRIENDS($fp_uid);
    $point = '0';
    while($row = $friend_array){
        $point += GET_POINT($row['fri_id']);
    }
    return $point;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What results/error are you getting?

Comment: Where is the rest, are you opening a database connection?

Comment: GET_POINT function works. i can get point. But i think GET_FRIENDS function doesnt work. No error but its return "Array".

Comment: @Erinç Fırtına Obviously, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array. What you really want is a multi-dimensional array like in @Krister Andersson's solution.

Comment: Besides what others mentioned, if your final scope is to get a sum of all points of all friends of a user... i would suggest you to make a 4th function which joins the tables and returns the sum of points directly from SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GET_FRIENDS` only returns the first row:

```
function GET_FRIENDS($fl_uid){
   if ($fl_uid){
       $friend_list_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend_list WHERE fid='{$fl_uid}'");
       $friend_list = array();
       // fetch all rows and add them to our $friend_list array
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($friend_list_query)) {
          $friend_list[] = $row;
       }
       return $friend_list;
   }
}
```

Then you would need to update your code to loop through each element in the array:

```
function GET_FRIEND_POINTS($fp_uid){
   $friend_array = GET_FRIENDS($fp_uid);
   $point = 0;
   // loop through each element in the array - you should also check so the array
   // isn't empty before the loop
   foreach ($friend_array as $row) {
      $point += GET_POINT($row['fri_id']);
   }
   return $point;
}
```